# Ajax get Date in dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, date

```
var d = new Date();
    var today_date = d.getDate() + '/' + month_name[d.getMonth()] + '/' + d.getFullYear();
```

This is how I am getting a date. It works with a slight problem. For todays date 7th of June 2011 it returns 7/11/2011,  what i want it to return is 07/11/2011?

Anyone know how?

Comment: If you are using Jquery change the format in the script available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
("0"+1).slice(-2);  // returns 01
("0"+10).slice(-2); // returns 10
```

Complete example:

```
var d = new Date(2011,1,1); // 1-Feb-2011
var today_date =
    ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" +
    ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + 
    d.getFullYear();
// 01/02/2011
```

Comment: Month names should be 01 02 03 etc not Jan Feb but apart from that thans it worked

Comment: @Beginner: I've made minor change to my answer

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could simply check the length of `d.getDate()`and if it's 1 then you add a zero at the beginning. But you would like to take a look at `format()` to format your dates?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format):

```
var d = new Date();
d.format("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this is more understandable.:

```
  var currentTime = new Date();
  var day = currentTime.getDate();
  var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = currentTime.getFullYear();

  if (day < 10){
  day = "0" + day;
  }

  if (month < 10){
  month = "0" + month;
  }

  var today_date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
  document.write(today_date.toString());
```

And result is :

`07/05/2011`

Comment: I like this solution. Its less cryptic.  Will make it easier for thos following behind me.  I did make a small change.  `var month = currentTime.getMonth();` gives you the month number starting at 0, so to get the current month in a 1-12 format I did  `var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;`

Comment: Thanks @Grayson for pointing me out this "month issue". I've updated my answer. Unfortunately sometimes _javascript_ doesn't comply with [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)